# Par ou ímpar de um array em PHP

Tags: php, array

Preciso criar um *array* e dizer se os valores dentro dele são par ou ímpar. Fiz o código dessa maneira:

```
<?php
$par_ou_impar = array(2,3,4,56,5,42,98,100);

 for ($i = 0; $i < count($par_ou_impar); $i++){
    if ($par_ou_impar % 2 == 0)
        echo "O Número é par: $par_ou_impar[$i]<br />";
    else
        echo "O Número é impar: $par_ou_impar[$i]<br />";
 }
?>
```

Ele me mostra todos os valores que estão dentro do *array* na tela, porém o resultado saí todos como ímpar.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

É simples, na verificação está comparando com o *array* e não com o elemento de *array*, como deveria. Ou seja, sempre dá falso porque um *array*, como um todo sempre é diferente do valor 0. Faltou os colchetes com o índice para pegar o elemento:

```
$par_ou_impar = array(2,3,4,56,5,42,98,100);
for ($i = 0; $i < count($par_ou_impar); $i++) {
    if ($par_ou_impar[$i] % 2 == 0) echo "O Número é par: $par_ou_impar[$i]<br />";
    else echo "O Número é impar: $par_ou_impar[$i]<br />";
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/hWQAGs). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/ofegwvqj-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/Algorithm/OddEven.php).

Já que está aprendendo, sugiro usar um controle que evitará o erro cometido:

```
$par_ou_impar = array(2, 3, 4, 56, 5, 42, 98, 100);
foreach ($par_ou_impar as $item) {
    if ($item % 2 == 0) echo "O Número é par: $item<br />";
    else echo "O Número é impar: $item<br />";
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/JrmHoG). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/gwgnobva-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/Algorithm/OddEven2.php).

O [`foreach`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) varre todo o *array*. Quase sempre é isto que deseja. Ele controla melhor isto para você. É sempre recomendável usá-lo, quando possível.

Pode simplificar mais ainda:

```
$par_ou_impar = array(2, 3, 4, 56, 5, 42, 98, 100);
foreach ($par_ou_impar as $item) echo "O Número é " . ($item % 2 == 0 ? "par: " : "impar: ") . $item . "<br>";
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/TE3kNP). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/aqxfqjlk-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/Algorithm/OddEven3.php).

Em algumas circunstâncias dá para usar a função [`each()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.each.php).

Comment: Valeu amigo, deu certo aqui! Obrigado pela explicação.

Answer (score 9):

Faltou-te um detalhe, usar `[$i]` aqui:

```
if ($par_ou_impar % 2 == 0)
                ^
```

para estares a comparar com o elemento que está a ser iterado. Assim o código certo será:

```
$par_ou_impar = array(2,3,4,56,5,42,98,100);

for ($i = 0; $i < count($par_ou_impar); $i++){
    if ($par_ou_impar[$i] % 2 == 0)
        echo "O Número é par: $par_ou_impar[$i]<br />";
    else
        echo "O Número é impar: $par_ou_impar[$i]<br />";
}
```

exemplo: https://ideone.com/OPnlAa

Comment: Valeu amigo, muito obrigado!

Answer (score 5):

Deixo minha contribuição com [array_map](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-map.php)

```
function checarNumeros($numeros){
   return ($numeros % 2 ) ? TRUE : FALSE;
}


$parOuImpar  = array(2,3,4,56,5,42,98,100);


$array  = array_map("checarNumeros", $parOuImpar);

print_r($array);
```

É retornado um array sendo que ,os ímpares retornam 1 e os pares retornam 0.

Comment: Não entendi a  down note

Answer (score 3):

Sei que já foi resolvido, mas deixo aqui uma alternativa:

```
<?php
   $par_ou_impar = array(2,3,4,56,5,42,98,100);
   for ($i = 0; $i < count($par_ou_impar); $i++){
       echo ($par_ou_impar[$i] % 2) ? "{$par_ou_impar[$i]} é impar\n" : "{$par_ou_impar[$i]} é par\n";
   }
?>
```