# criação de formulário PHP

Tags: php, html

Estou com bastante dúvidas com a matéria esse ano que está sendo PHP, e essa atividade:

> 3) Crie um formulário PHP que mostre os números pares entre 400 e 545
>   <sub>[foto da atividade](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ndoX.jpg)</sub>

É algo bastante simples, de acordo com meu professor, mas estou tendo dificuldades em resolvê-la, se alguém puder me dar uma força eu ficaria feliz. Abraços

Comment: Está pergunta é similar a está: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/110925/par-ou-%C3%ADmpar-de-um-array-em-php

Comment: Faça um laço que comece com o 400 e termine com 545, divida o número corrente por 2, verifique o módulo da operação e mostre o resultado. [PHP Operadores](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.operators.arithmetic.php)

Answer (score 2):

Uma solução para este problema seria a seguinte:

```
<?php 
for ($x =400; $x<=545; $x++){
    if ($x % 2 == 0){
        echo $x . "<br>";
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Se vc só quer os números pares e já começa do 400 (que é par), não é mais fácil pular de 2 em 2? -> `for ($x =400; $x<=545; $x += 2)` - assim nem precisa do `if` :-)