# $arr = array (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10); como faço para somar apenas os numeros pares dentro do array em php?

Tags: php

tenho um Array:

```
$arr = array (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10);
```

Gostaria de saber como faço para somar apenas os números pares dentro do array do vetor em PHP?

Comment: Caro rafael o basico é fundamental, podem até lhe sugerir array_filter, como se fosse a solução de todos problemas, mas o básico é essencial para se aprender programação, então for e foreach sempre resolverão de forma mais clara e reaprovetavel a aprender sem recursos avançadados, com a resposta https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/110927/3635 basta dentro da IF para checar se é par, somar a uma variavel fora do `for` e após o ciclo do for terá o resultado.

Comment: para somar usaria isso: <?php $arrays = array (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10); $soma = 0; foreach($arrays as $array){ if(is_int($array/2)){ $soma = $soma+$array; } } echo "soma: ". $soma;

Answer (score 2):

Use a função [`array_reduce`](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-reduce.php) que reduz um array para um único valor através de um processo iterativo via função callback.

```
<?php

$arr = array (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10);

//Para cada elemento array aplica uma função redutora
$soma = array_reduce($arr, function($carry, $item){  
  //Testa par ver se o número é par se for soma o elemento senão mantém o valor
  return $item % 2 == 0 ? $carry + $item : $carry;
});

echo $soma;
```

<sup>Teste no [Repl.it](https://replit.com/@RonaldoVasques/InferiorCornsilkInverse#main.php)</sup>

Outra possibilidade é iterando sobre os elementos da array e testando para ver se são pares

```
<?php

$arr = array (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10);

$soma = 0;

//Para cada elemento do array
foreach($arr as $item){
   if ($item % 2 == 0) $soma += $item; //O Soma apenas se for par
}

echo $soma;
```

<sup>Teste no [Repl.it](https://replit.com/@RonaldoVasques/ProfitableFloweryPyramid#main.php)</sup>

Comment: Caro Augusto, vale ressaltar na resposta o porque usou o terceiro parametro como `$arr, callbac, 1`, para resumir, a conta é de multiplicação, se o argumento fosse omitido o resultado seria zero, já que `$carry` iniciaria como NULL mesmo, logo internamente o PHP trataria a operação matematica como zero a multiplicação https://repl.it/@inphinit/multiplication-vs-null-php

Comment: um dos motivos do porque não formulei a resposta e raramente sugiro funções como `array_reduce`, é porque eventualmente isto leva a pessoa a pular passos importantes do aprendizado básico, não estou dizendo que devam seguir o que eu acredito, mas em quase todas areas da TI vejo o mesmo problema, uso de coisas sem entendimento real, e me sou obrigado a dar o braço a torcer, o SOen e pt viraram sites de copia e cola

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento eu não sei de onde tirei a multiplicação. Fiz a correção. E sim na multiplicação um `$carry == 0` zeraria o resultado. Adicionei também um exemplo utilizando iteração por laço.

Comment: Não é sindrome do TOC não (apesar de muita gente insistir que sofro disto :P) ... mas parenteses não são necessários antes do `?` em `return ($item % 2 == 0) ? $carry + $item : $carry;` ... quero dizer, se fosse separas a lógica ou até organizar a identação acaso houvesse quebra de linha seria OK, mas ali é um pouco redundante. PS: +1 pelo edit

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento que isso. Toda orientação para melhoria é bem vinda. Eu vou não mexer agora porque estou jantando e passei só para dar uma olhada mesmo. Quando eu voltar eu acerto. Porém se você sentir a necessidade de editar qualquer uma de minhas publicação eu tenho plena confiança em sua intervenção.